# Solving a large system of nonlinear equations

Tags: equation-solving, system-variables

I have a system of 80 nonlinear equations with 64 variables to solve in Mathematica but it takes a lot of time (about two hours) and then it return "no more memory available" knowing that I have 8GB Ram on Windows 8 64 bits.
The system is

```
sys=Flatten[Table[Table[Table[Table[Sum[a[i,j,k]a[k,l,h]-a[j,k,l]a[i,l,h],{l,1,4}]==0,{h,1,4}],{k,j,4}],{j,i,4}],{i,1,4}]]
```

Variables are `var=Flatten[Table[a[i,j,k],{i,1,4},{j,1,4},{k,1,4}]]`

First I used `Solve[sys,var]` which did not work and also  `NSolve` did not work (as described above).
How can I make it work ? or at least find the number of unknowns that equal zero (that what I'm interested in).

Comment: There are no equations here...

Comment: @MariusLadegårdMeyer : It has been corrected now.

Comment: What do you mean by "...NSolve did not work"?

Comment: Probably just to large for `GroebnerBasis` to have any hope.

Comment: FYI this has a trivial solution where all `a[_,_,_]` are equal..  I posed it as a least squares problem, `FindMinimum` readily returns `{a[1, 1, 1] -> 1., a[1, 1, 2] -> 1., a[1, 1, 3] -> 1., 
 a[1, 1, 4] -> 1. ...`

Comment: @dimitris I mean that it took much time and much memory (more than what I have and I got an error message).

Answer (score 2):

This is really more of a comment, but it's too long. I would try to solve this starting with a smaller analogous problem. For instance, the `n=2` version of this readily gives an answer:

```
n = 2; 
sys = Flatten[Table[Table[Table[Table[
    Sum[a[i, j, k] a[k, l, h] - a[j, k, l] a[i, l, h], {l, 1, n}] ==  0, 
        {h, 1, n}], {k, j, n}], {j, i, n}], {i, 1, n}]];
var = Flatten[Table[a[i, j, k], {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, n}, {k, 1, n}]];
Solve[sys, var]
```

But if you look at this answer, the solution contains terms like: `a[1, 1, 2] -> 0` while at the same time containing `a[2, 2, 2] -> a[1, 2, 2]^2/a[1, 1, 2]`. So even in the `n=2` case, this is quite suspicious. The `n=3` case takes longer to run than I have patience for. Using `Reduce` instead of `Solve` might also shed some more light on the issue.

Comment: This does not help much, What if set $m$ values of a[i,j,k] to be zero and test whether the system is verified (I'm searching for the largest value of such $m<64$) but it seems too complicated, do you have an idea  ?

Comment: The only other thing I can think of would be to try and rewrite the system in matrix/tensor form. Maybe something would pop out. Here again, it might be worth looking at smaller versions first.